# Problem connecting to my email with a Centos7 server

Tags: php, imap, centos7, gmail-imap

I developed a simple code, with the php language, to connect to my email and count the number of emails received, using the local Window 10 server.

```
<?php
// server IMAP per la connessione
$server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}";

// account Gmail
$login = 'login@gmail.com';
// password per l'accesso a Gmail
$password = 'password';

// connessione IMAP ad un account Gmail
$connessione = imap_open($server, $login, $password);

$conteggio = imap_num_msg($connessione);

echo $conteggio."<br>";
```

By enabling the IMAP protocol on Gmail and enabling access to less secure apps, the code does 
not give any kind of error.

The problem arises when I try to execute this code into a Centos 7 server machine.
I installed the IMAP protocol compatible with my PHP 7.3 version, using this command line: yum --enablerepo=centos-sclo-sclo-testing install sclo-php73-php-imapservice imapd restart.
Once the package is successfully downloaded, I restart the server machine and go check on

```
<?php

phpinfo(); 

?>
```

and notice that the IMAP is enabled.

```
imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007f
SSL Support enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled
```

After this check, if I try to run my initial code, this error message appears to me on output: warning: imap_open(): couldn’t open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert} even though i have enabled imap and by actvaing.

PS. the password and login are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't seem to be PHP related, but connection related, especially if the script works on a different machine.

There are two things you need to check.

- Can you outbound connect on port 993 (is it open for OUT connections). You can try telnet to check that and if it doesn't work verify your Linux Firewall settings.
- Do you have SELinux enabled and if you do did you check your audit log for AVC denials? It you have issues you may need to enable your httpd_can_network_connect or even do an audit2allow as the port might be non-standard. Be careful what you are doing as you can disrupt security on your server.